# How to read a specific element from a certain user

Tags: ruby

I'm having problems with this code:

```
if @msg =~ /!myxp/i
  file = File.open("myxp.txt") do |record|
    record.each do |item|
      id, xp, name = item.chomp.split(', ')
      puts "#{name}, your ID is #{id} and you have #{xp}XP!"
    end
  end
```

My `myxp.txt` has:

```
6753, 50, User1
58763, 30, User2
90845, 80, User3
```

`User2` says !myxp and it sends all of the other ones, too (User1 and User3).

How do I make it only works for User2 instead of everyone?

Comment: You are missing an `end` keyword for your `if` statement, not sure if that is the problem or a copy-paste error since you didn't provide any information regarding to why you think your code is wrong.

Comment: Syntax issues aside, this does seem like it should work *if* the format of your file matches what you're saying. Some things to consider: Use the CSV format and the built-in [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to make your file format standardized and eliminate any potential errors when parsing, or if the data is constantly changing then use a database, even [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) to start. Always indent properly so that syntax errors stand out.

Comment: Or many I did ``.each``.

Are there other ways that I can do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to isolate the XP value for a particular user you need to narrow it down using a filter or a condition:

```
case (@msg.downcase)
when /!myxp/
  File.open("myxp.txt") do |record|
    record.each do |item|
      id, xp, name = item.chomp.split(', ')

      # Skip this entry unless name matches my name
      next unless (name == @name)

      puts "#{name}, your ID is #{id} and you have #{xp}XP!"
    end
  end
end
```

I've taken the liberty of switching your `if` that tests commands into a `case` because this makes adding other commands simple and keeps things organized.

I'm not sure where the person's name is stored, so it's `@name` in this example.

Comment: If User4 isn't stored in there, how can it add ``131213, 0, User4`` in? file.puts "131213, 0, User4"

Comment: While you can get a long way with a flat file, at this point you want to use a database. If you don't know how to do that, a library like [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) can make it easy to get started. In that case it's just `User.create(name: 'User4', xp: 0)` and it will generate an ID for you. ActiveRecord can work with SQLite, so there's no database server required, it's just a database in a file.

Answer (score 0):

As tadman mentioned you can also use the built-in CSV functionality.

```
require 'csv'

@user = 'User2'

CSV.read('myxp.txt', col_sep: ', ').each do |id, xp, name| 
  puts "#{name}, your ID is #{id} and you have #{xp} XP!" if name == @user
end
```

You're better off using a database however for these things, it'll require a little bit of reading initially but will make things easier going forward.